# Jquery UI date Picker disable enable Sunday, Thursday and disable specific dates

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to enable only Thursdays and Sundays but also disable some specific Sundays or Thursdays. 
I'm trying with this function but it's not working yet:

```
<script>
    var unavailableDates = ["2013-03-31", "2013-03-24"];

    function disabledays(date) {

        ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
        if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) == 0) {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"]
        } else {

        //Show only sundays and thuersdays
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 0 || day == 4)];

    }

$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disabledays

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The code that builds a date string does not add a `0` to the month portion. You could change your `unavailableDates` array.
2. You need to check the return value of `$.indexOf` to see if it's `>=` 0 instead of just equal to zero.

With both changes:

```
var unavailableDates = ["2013-3-31", "2013-3-24"];

function disabledays(date) {
    var ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
    if ($.inArray(ymd, unavailableDates) >= 0) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        //Show only sundays and thuersdays
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 0 || day == 4)];
    }
}

$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disabledays
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XJKbV/

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it was the piece of code I was trying to understand.